# Calculating Top Ten Categories in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm using an SSIS package to update my contents daily basis. There are thousands of contents which have different Moderation ID's and I want to calculate top ten categories FOR EACH Moderation ID. Before I realized that I should calculate it for each ModerationId, I used this query to get the Contents to be updated:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ModerationId, Category, COUNT(ContentSeqNum) AS Total FROM Content
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ModerationId, Category ORDER BY ModerationId, Total DESC
```

And that was a faulty approach because this query calculates top ten Categories for all the data, which should be different top ten categories for different ModerationId's.

How can I change this query to calculate Top 10 Categories for each ModerationId?

Comment: Just `ORDER BY Total DESC` and thats it (not sure what is `ModId`).

Comment: It's ModerationId. But I'm not sure if just ordering by total would work because that will just take top ten of ALL DATA, not special for each ModerationId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Window Function` to get the to calculate top ten `categories` for `Moderation ID`. Try this.

```
SELECT moderationid, 
       category, 
       total 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY moderationid 
                   ORDER BY Count(contentseqnum)) Rn, 
               moderationid, 
               category, 
               Count(contentseqnum)               AS Total 
        FROM   content 
        WHERE  category IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP  BY moderationid, 
                  category) A 
WHERE  rn <= 10
```

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake, I was trying to add the comment to the other answer. This still works, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP(10) ModerationId, Category, COUNT(ContentSeqNum) OVER(PARTITION BY ModerationId ORDER BY ModerationId) AS Total 
FROM Content
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: FYI - You cannot use **order by** in sub query unless you have **TOP** keyword

Comment: @NoDisplayName sorry, no need for the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Use Row_number() function

```
select * from
(
        select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by ModerationId order by ModerationId) as sno 
        from Content WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
) as t
where sno<=10
```

Find more methods at http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10845/return-top-n-rows.aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, but this didn't work for me. It shows multiple rows for the same categories.